# I want to search list elements in txt file

Tags: python, list, search, element, readline

I want to search for list elements in txt file. However with this code I don't get the desired result. I have tried several solutions, but none of them really worked.

```py
def run(self):
    hostname = self.queue.get()
    with open('allhosts.txt', "r+") as file1:
        fileline1 = file1.readlines()
        for x in hostname:
            for line in fileline1:
                if x in line:
                    self.found.emit(hostname)
                else:
                    self.notFound.emit(hostname)
```

Comment: What result do you get and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: With this code it returns for the `if` and `else` statement as well. So it is finding them and not finding them.

Comment: That can't be true. If the `if` branch is executed, the `else` branch is not executed, and vice versa (at least not in the same iteration). Please show a [mre].

Comment: What do you expect `x` is?

Answer (score 1):

Use regx in this case

```
import re

str = open('a.txt', 'r').read()

m = re.search('(?<=hostname)(.*)', str)
print ("hostname",(m.groups()))
```

If you dont get output. please drop text file screenshot